# SQL multiple join confusion

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 3 tables that I'm joining(the contents should be irrelevant):
Students
Courses
StudentsCourses

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((Students
INNER JOIN StudentsCourses ON Students.ID  
StudentsCourses.studentID)
INNER JOIN Courses on StudentsCourses.courseID = Courses.ID)
ORDER BY Students.firstName
```

My problem:

I understand in the first join that I'm combining Students and StudentsCourses. What I don't understand is what the second join is joining to. Is it the result of the Students and StudentsCourses join? Something like (Students + StudentsCourses) + Courses. How does the second join know what StudentsCourses.courseID is if I didn't explicitly specify that table to join to?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the formatting to work.

Comment: studentCourses contain only foreing key of courid in order to fetch course name it have to join with the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my formatting, but I don't understand the answer. I'm looking to understand in detail what SQL is doing in each step. I understand how the first join works(joining Students and StudentsCourses). I don't understand how it relates the second join.

Comment: try to clear your basic about foreign key and primary do ? why they need in database ? etc etc

Comment: I found something that explains it. It looks like each join applies to the derived table from the previous join.

Comment: is This Your Query format? Unable To understand format of Query

Answer (score 0):

You have to think in terms of "sets" in SQL. When you are defining your FROM clause you are preparing a statement that will be interpreted by the database engine's optimizer.

What do you mean "if I didn't explicitly specify that table to join to?"

So far in this statement you only have 2 options, Students or StudentCourses, because those are the 2 tables defined before the second JOIN.